# How to do text recognition in a language that doesn't use the roman alphabet

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I am trying to reconize a single letter or character from a non-roman character set by edge detection. I want to extract single characters from a text image. When I identify that letter or character I want to be able to print it like a text recognizer does.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok. So what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: I would suggest to look into `Classify`, but without more concrete examples and use cases it's hard to help you further. `Classify` would not bother with edge detection (well, under the cover it probably might), but if you only strive for character recognition, explicit edge detection may not be so critical.

Comment: Ya Thank U... I will try. I think classify i used to English language only. This is the other language. I think classify is not used.